# Hitting time for 2-dimensional Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stopping-times

Fix $a>0$ and let $(A_t^-)_{t\geq0}$ and $(A_t^+)_{t\geq 0}$ be two independent one-dimensional Brownian motions, starting from $-a$ and $a$, respectively. Set $$T=\inf\{t\geq0:A_t^-=A_t^+\}.$$ I am tasked to show that $T<\infty$ almost surely and to find a density function $T$. I really don't know how to do this - the hint given is to consider an orthogonal transformation of $(A_t^-,A_t^+)_{t\geq0}$ which would also be a Brownian motion, but I'm unsure how to use this. Any help anyone could give would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may write the given Brownian motions as:
$$\begin{align*}
A_t^{-} &= -a + B_t^{(1)} \\
A_t^{+} &= a + B_t^{(2)}
\end{align*}$$
where $B_t^{(1)}$ and $B_t^{(2)}$ are independent standard Brownian motions (i.e. they start at zero). Then, $A_t^{-} = A_t^{-}$ if and only if $\frac{1}{2}(B_t^{(1)} - B_t^{(2)}) = a$. Notice that $W_t = \frac{1}{2}(B_t^{(1)} - B_t^{(2)})$ is a standard Brownian motion, so that we may re-write the given stopping time as $$T = T_a^{W} = \inf\{ t \geq 0 \, : \, W_t = a\}$$
From then on, you may conclude that $T<\infty$ almost surely by, for instance, appealing to the fact that $\limsup_{t\to \infty} W_t = \infty$.

For the density of this stopping time, you may consult [this other MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1286391/brownian-motion-hitting-time-distribution?rq=1), or maybe [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4409333/density-of-first-hitting-time-of-brownian-motion-from-its-cdf).